# Spring SMTP throws java.net.sockettimeoutexception: Read timed out when used in Multi-Threaded Environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, email, smtp

I send Email using Spring mail SMTP through Spring Batch. Sending each mail takes 1 second at least. And we would be sending 1000 mails per Batch job. Due the 1 second per mail , it seems it'll take lot of time to send all those 1000+ mails. So I planned to use multi-threading to send all emails in a chunk(size=100) of the job. And I succeeded a bit (only a bit) in sending mails with this approach.

The multi-threading works as long as the the total mail count is very small , like 40 email per Batch(Not even the size of the chunk). if the mail counts exceeds the count The SMTP throws `java.net.sockettimeoutexception read timed out`.
Even increasing the timeout is not working here. But when I send mails without multithreads, they work perfectly.

**application.properties**

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ehlo=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=false

spring.mail.properties[mail.smtp.connectiontimeout]=10000
spring.mail.properties[mail.smtp.timeout]=10000
spring.mail.properties[mail.smtp.writetimeout]=10000
spring.mail.properties[mail.mime.charset]=UTF-8
```

**Writer**

```
    @Autowired
    EmailSender emailSender;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Collection<Callable<Map<BBEmailOutreach, Boolean>>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    items.stream().filter(item -> item != null).forEach(item -> {
       tasks.add(new ParallelMail(item, emailSender));
    }

    try {
        futureMailStatus = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EmailSender.java**

```
public class EmailSender {
    
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendEmail(EmailInfo emailInfo) {

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,
                        true);
                message.setTo(emailInfo.getToEmailAddress().split(","));
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailInfo.getFromEmailAddress()));
                message.setSubject(emailInfo.getSubject());
                message.setText(emailInfo.getMessage(), true);
                if(null != emailInfo.getCc() && emailInfo.getCc().length >1)
                {
                    message.setCc(emailInfo.getCc());
                }
                if (emailInfo.getAttachmentPath() != null) {
                    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(
                            emailInfo.getAttachmentPath());
                    message.addAttachment(emailInfo.getAttachmentName(), file);
                }
            }
        };
        this.javaMailSender.send(preparator);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Please advise what can be done to use mutli-threading without any error.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org/) (open source), which also supports [advanced batch sending](http://www.simplejavamail.org/features.html#section-sending-asynchronously) (even using multiple mail server clusters).

Comment: Actually my company uses SMTP only right now. Maybe I can try that too.